# Indexed view usability

Tags: sql-server

I have an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW ptv.vw_mokiniai_2
 WITH SCHEMABINDING
 AS 
  SELECT 
    T1.year_name,
    T2.person_id,
    T2.year,
    T2.person_position,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS [aggregated number]
  FROM Table1 AS T1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
     ON T1.year = T2.year
  GROUP BY T1.year_name,
    T2.person_id,
    T2.year,
    T2.person_position
```

With unique clustered index on columns

```
T1.year_name, T2.person_id, T2.year, T2.person_position
```

I need the query optimizer to use this indexed view on query

```
SELECT 
    T1.year_name, 
    COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT T3.person_id) AS [persons_per_year]
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
              T2.person_id,
              T2.year,
              T2.person_position
            FROM Table2 AS T2 
            GROUP BY T2.person_id, T2.year, T2.person_position
            ) AS T3 
    ON T1.year = T3.year
GROUP BY T1.year_name
```

The query must be with derived table, because COGNOS generates this query and I do not want to edit the multidimensional model. Someone have an idea how could it be done? Maybe the only way to optimize the query is remove derived table(means I have to edit multidimensional model)? Any suggestions (view editing and final query editing) would be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered creating an indexed view on the derived table query alone?

Comment: I've tried that..did not work

Comment: Are you running Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Yes. It is Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer with a repro script that uses the view index.  Importantly, year is the first column of the view index to facilitate the `JOIN` clause in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below uses the indexed view in my test.  If this doesn't work in your environment, perhaps there is a difference not evident in the code you posted.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
    (
      year varchar(10)
    , year_name varchar(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
    (
      year varchar(10)
    , person_id varchar(10)
    , person_position varchar(10)
    );
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_mokiniai_2
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  T2.person_id
          , T2.year
          , T2.person_position
          , COUNT_BIG(*) AS [aggregated number]
    FROM    dbo.Table2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T2.person_id
          , T2.year
          , T2.person_position
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON vw_mokiniai_2(year, person_id, person_position)
GO

SELECT 
    T1.year_name, 
    COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT T3.person_id) AS [persons_per_year]
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
              T2.person_id,
              T2.year,
              T2.person_position
            FROM Table2 AS T2 
            GROUP BY T2.person_id, T2.year, T2.person_position
            ) AS T3 
    ON T1.year = T3.year
GROUP BY T1.year_name
GO
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when trying to create usable indexed view. It works, thanks.